# How do I get the right Windows-1252 encoding in Jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

I have to make a POST with some values, but there's an encrypted token generated in windows-1252.

When I do inspect the DOM elements and copy this token (delete and re-insert for testing) and submit the form, it works fine. But I have to get this token through Jsoup and send it back.
The problem is that the token has an special character (0x9D) which is not recognized when setting the charset in Jsoup's Document parse (even in Chrome DevTool's Sources tab is not recognized).

The square character is the one not recognized: €“sytœ

Long story short, in Chrome's elements inspection the square appears as an different character, but in Sources it doesn't appear, as in Jsoup as well. Inserting the values copied from inspection and doing the submit manually, it works, but in Jsoup doesn't work. The only difference in values is this missing character, and without him, manually submit doesn't work either.

Does someone have an idea of what I have to make to get the right encoding? Thanks!